# How do you load a node inside of another node?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, ajax

A node has several text links or thumbnails loaded from a view. For the purpose of this question, lets suppose they're thumbnails and the area with the thumbnails lets call it the "head" of the node.

Those thumbnails link to other nodes. To be able to understand the scenario am trying place here. Lets call the nodes that the thumbnails link to "*Subnodes*". The Area under the thumbnails, is a area where you want to load a "subnode" from the thumbnail clicked. Lets call this area the "footer".

The goal here is keep the original node with the thumbnails or text links ("Header") at the top of the page AND load the subnode in the "footer". The ideal method would involve some AJAX to keep the page load away from the end user. Although this is not required because a solution with a page load is acceptable.

*Extra consideration to anyone who purposes a solution using AJAX.*

Comment: Down voting the question and not commenting on it to help me improve the question is not very useful to anyone...

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking; try leading your question with a clear question: "How do I load a node on a page using AJAX?"

Comment: Well the solution doesn't HAVE to be AJAX. I'm more concerned about getting a solution that would explain how to load one node inside of another. I will modify my question and hopefully that will clarify the misunderstanding.

Comment: please explain how those thumbnails are generated in the first place?  Are they node reference fields that are populated in the original node or something else? also, what version of drupal are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Peekaboo; Ajax field formatter](http://drupal.org/project/peekaboo) module.

> Provides the ability to load the contents of a field via Ajax.
>
> #### Use cases
>
> - **Field output that is heavy on resources**
>     Some fields, such as the *reference fields, can contain a tremendous amount of overhead when formatting the output for the field. This module allows the page output to load without calculating the formatted output of the field, and the field contents can be subsequently loaded into the page with Ajax.
> - **Field output that takes up too much space**
>     Peekaboo can be used to initially hide certain fields that take up a lot of space, like maps or images, only to be revealed later at the user's request.
> - **Fields that reveal more information**
>     Peekaboo can also be used purely for the Ajax functionality as a gimmick to reveal more information.

Comment: Cool module, never heard of that one